# Ruby Modules methods outside ClassMethods

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to understand how this works and would be great if someone could help me. I've got a module which looks like the below:

```
module Activity::Track
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def track_now(name, options={})
      add_activity activity(verb: name)
    end
  end

  protected

  def activity(options={})
  end

  def add_activity(activity_item)
  end
end
```

What I'm doing is calling the `track_now` method from my model, which is fine and works well but I can't call the `add_activity` and `activity` methods. I don't understand how I can call them from within the `ClassMethods` module. Can someone explain how I can do this?

I have seen this in another project but the protected methods were called by creating a `define_method` and then calling this via `send :after_create :define_method`. How does this work?

Comment: Do you mixin your module somewhere?

Comment: I do `include Timeline::Track` and then call the method from my model `track_now(:new_item, user: :pilot)`, Is this what your asking?

Comment: Simply put: you can’t. A class doesn’t know about its instances, and thus a “class method” cannot call an instance method.

Comment: @Max Give an example then. Your answer also completely glosses over the class method `track_now` by eliminating it.

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Comment: Here is an example of where I'm referring to: https://github.com/felixclack/redis-timeline/blob/master/lib/timeline/track.rb

Comment: @Peter No instance methods are being called there in the class method. It’s calling the method `after_create` and passing the method name as an argument.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall can you explain how its working from the 'after_create' method. How would I get it to work with the `track_now` method so I can call the methods outside of the `ClassMethods` block? Can you recommend anything for me to read to make me understand what is happening?

Comment: `after_create` is a class method, for setting up callbacks.  So other class methods can safely call it.  You simply can't call instance methods from class methods, it doesn't make any sense.  Post more details about what you're trying to accomplish and we can help you.

Comment: @NickVeys I'd like to call this `add_activity activity(verb: name)` from a `ClassMethod` (track_now) which I can call from any model when I include the Module. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, then can you make `add_activity` and `activity` class-level methods?  Or do they have to operate on instance data?

Comment: Just tried making them as class-level methods but the `send(options[:actor])` won't work. error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method `user'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to call an instance method from a class method. I don't recommend you doing that, but if you really want, you can try as following:

```
def track_now(name, options={})
  self.new.instance_eval {add_activity activity(verb: name)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a new file `track_now.rb` which was a duplicate of `track.rb` but made all the methods a `ClassMethod`.

Does anyone know how I can use the protected methods from the instance and class methods from both files, this would be a great benefit?